# Spring mvc and Jackson Compatibity Issue

Tags: java, json, spring

I am building a Web app using Spring Web-mvc.I ap also using Rest Webservices.
I am using Jackson for Java to Json conversion.Please find below my pom.xml  with complete set of dependencies details:

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
        <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160810</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.xmlschema</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlschema-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.11</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am getting following exception while submitting a ajax request to server:

```
  Root cause of ServletException.
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.forType(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectWriter;
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:278)
at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:231)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:174)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I am using Weblogic 12.2.1 for deployment.
Can anyone help me out with this compatibility issue?

Comment: The default dependency of Spring 4.3.6 to Jackson is version 2.8.6, why are you trying to use an older version (2.7.0)? Also consider removing the jackson-mapper-asl dependency, it is really old and has been - afaik - superseded by jackson-databind.

Comment: If you comment the dependencies `jackson-core` and `jackson-databind`, wouldn't Spring provide you the defaults being used by it? Moreover, if you want to override, as @MarkRotteveel says better to override with a higher version

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel, I have made the changes suggested by you.But didn't work.It cause same exception.

Comment: @Vikas, Jackson dependencies are required otherwise it cause Runtime exception at deployment time

Comment: Given that it is declared as [an explicit dependency of spring-webmvc](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.pom) the problem is more likely that you are also pulling in an older version as a transitive dependency somewhere else.

Comment: have edited the post with entire set of <dependencies> tag @Mark Rotteveel

Comment: @SumitGhosh try having `jackson-annotations` dependency also (same version)

Comment: Also this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44764657/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-com-fasterxml-jackson-databind-objectwriter-fortype

Comment: Thanks vikas.Adding weblogic.xml configuration solved my issue